# One Drive Multipart upload error HTTP 400 Bad Request

Tags: multipartform-data, codenameone, restful-url, onedrive, bad-request

When i was doing upload file to onedrive with following:

> ```
> HTTP POST https://apiis.live.net/v5.0/{foldid}/files?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
>
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary={boundary}
>
> --{boundary}
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="{filename}"
> Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>
> {File content goes here}
> --{boundary}
> ```

by which I follow the guide from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659726.aspx

It always give me error "java.lang.Exception: HTTP 400. Bad Request".
Would one drive team or anyone help to give me advice what it was going wrong?

Thanks and Best Regards,
Ronald

Answer (score 1):

It seems your request is malformed. 
 I don't know how one drive works but after a quick overview on your link, did you try to remove the 'HTTP' before 'POST' header ? 

Or is your file content properly sended ?

Answer (score 1):

From the url, `https://apis.live.net/v5.0/{folderid}/files?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}`, this would indicate you are using the deprecated LiveConnect API.  I would recommend using the supported APIs located at https://api.onedrive.com with the upload method described here https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_put.htm where the request does not need the multipart mime schema

```
PUT .../drive/root:/{parent-path}/{filename}:/content
Content-Type: text/plain

The contents of the file goes here.
```

Get more information about these APIs at https://dev.onedrive.com If the updated uploading method is still causing you trouble, please make sure to include the full HTTP response headers and body.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! May I know if I would like to upload large files, need i use multipart where i found in https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_post.htm?

On the other hand,  is the url "PUT .../drive/root:/{parent-path}/{filename}:/content" the "..." meaning "https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0"?

Comment: Sorry for that i'm quite new to do onedrive development, from the URL, not need it access token or where should i use the access token kind of? Thanks!!!

Comment: Every request to the OneDrive service should include the header like: `Authorization: Bearer AbCdEf123456`  You can use the same authentication token that you used with the apis.live.net service

Comment: I would not recommend using the multi-part upload, is is there for legacy purposes, instead use  the resumable upload api documented here https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_large_files.htm

Comment: He is using the Codename One API to map to the REST API of onedrive. I'm not familiar with the onedrive API but I can help with the Codename One terms for REST operations

Comment: We have tried resumable upload before but it is because our app implementation will encrypt the stream and send so that we don't know the content length. Would you have any alternative and solution for that? Thanks!

Comment: There are many encryption schemes that will have a deterministic output length, check to see if helper functions are available within your crypto libraries to determine these details otherwise using block ciphers you could calculate the number of blocks necessary of size N to store the file + padding  and then add required the storage constant for the cipher details, which should be agnostic of the length of the encrypted file

Comment: Actually can we use back the deprecated LiveConnect API like the question mentioned because we are used developed on it. We are running out of time and the new API causes us to change tremendous codes written before. Many thanks!